# How can I show custom alerts in UWP or WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I need UWP app or wpf application that shows or sends notifications which will show in full screen also on lock screen and screen saver(in short override all conditions and show the alert).

I have created one sample app in UWP that uses `ToastNotification` provided by microsoft but we can not customize it's size.

```
 public static void ShowAlertNotification()
        {
            var toastContent = new ToastContent()
            {
                Visual = new ToastVisual()
                {
                    BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                    {
                        Children =
                        {
                            new AdaptiveText()
                            {
                                Text = "High Alert Message"
                            },
                            new AdaptiveText()
                            {
                                Text = "Alert from Notifications App"
                            },
                            new AdaptiveImage()
                            {
                                Source = "Assets/caution.png"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
                {
                    Buttons =
                    {
                        new ToastButton("Ignore", "action=ignore&callId=938163")
                        {
                            ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Protocol,
                            ImageUri = "Assets/stop.png"
                        },
                        new ToastButton("Acknowledged", "action=answer&callId=938163")
                        {
                            ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Foreground,
                            ImageUri = "Assets/correct.png"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Launch = "action=answer&callId=938163",
                Scenario = ToastScenario.IncomingCall,
                DisplayTimestamp = DateTime.Now,
            };

            // Create the toast notification
            var toastNotif = new ToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml());

            // And send the notification
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastNotif);
        }
```

Default `ToastNotification` have predefined type like calender, call etc. But I need it for full screen.
[image: here]

I have also tried with creating win form in full screen than I can call it using service but I think it is not preferable.

I need this type of app for school which can send emergency alert to the parents.

So any Ideas or suggestions on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We could not specify the width and height of the toast in UWP, so you can't set it to full screen. You could use the Popup and set its size to full screen to display it when using the App, but it won't display on lock screen.

Comment: You can actually "build" your proper notification screen and be able to customize it as much as you want and make is visibile or not in your code. (being cancelable etc.)

Answer (score 1):

With the [Azure Notification Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/), you can send a toast notification to the mobile UWP app and you'll get that information even when the app is not running.

In the UWP, the visual appearance of the toast notification depends on the actual device the app is running on. You can, although, extend it using the syntax description present in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts) but, as Faywang - MSFT mentions in the comments,

> you can't set it to full screen (because we can't specify the width and height of the toast)